# Ignore/skip first row of csv with filter

Tags: python, csv

Is it possible to ignore or skip the first row in a CSV file with `filter`?

```
filtered = filter(lambda p: celery == p[7],reader)
csv.writer(open(filename, 'w',newline=''), delimiter=',').writerows(filtered)
```

I'm trying to read and filter only the 7th row containing the word `celery` but because the filter keeps reading the header `stuff` it messes up the line under it.

```
                                                          Stuff                                                                                                   
Apple Pear Orange Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato Celery Lettuce Carrot
Apple Pear Orange Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato Celery Lettuce Carrot
Apple Pear Orange Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato Celery Lettuce Carrot
```

I think because it can't find `celery` it just cuts off the line under it?

```
ge Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato Celery Lettuce Carrot
Apple Pear Orange Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato Celery Lettuce Carrot
Apple Pear Orange Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato Celery Lettuce Carrot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) before you construct `filtered`:

> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its next() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

Example:

```
next(reader, None) # skips a line - default set to None
filtered = filter(lambda p: celery == p[7],reader)
```

Comment: Thank you, how would I insert it into this? `reader =(csv.reader(open(r'{1}\{0}\{0}.csv'.format(man_year,queue)),delimiter=',')`

Comment: Just add `next(reader, None)` after you construct a reader to exhaust one line.